# RESTful API Client

Tags: api, rest, client

I am new to RESTful API client development. I have a got the sample client code to integrate to REST Server. Below is the the snap shoot of same.

```
public TsbPublishClient() {
    client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
    webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("publication");
}
public <T> T getJson(Class<T> responseType, String product, String version, String category) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("registry/{0}/{1}/{2}", new Object[]{product, version, category}));
    return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
}

public void close() {
    client.close();
}
```

My question is how do i invoke the getJson() method from my main class. The return type is  T and it accepts responseType parameter which is of type Class <T>

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you write this code? I I don't see what the problem is. The only question I see is "how do I call this method?" If you did not write this code, I wonder if it's even set to work for your domain. Please elaborate on what it is that's so hard about calling this method?

Comment: If you didn't write it, and it's not fit for your domain, then you can't call it. You just need to write your own code.

Comment: Hi peeskillet, No I got the above class file to integrate with REST Server.

Comment: Just do something like `Product product  = getJson(Product.class, p, v, c);` Or what ever it is the return Java type y want to unmarshal to. Whatever class is passed to the first argument, that will be the return type. Maybe do some research on generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised that you want to use JAX-WS to access a RESTful API. In this technology, a web service operation invocation is represented by an XML-based protocol such as SOAP.

There are several technologies to do a call to a RESTful applications. Here are two of them:

- **[Restlet](http://restlet.com/products/restlet-framework/)** - a lightweight and robust Java REST framework that tackles both client and server sides.
- **JAX-RS** (JSR 311: JAX-RS: The Java API for RESTful Web Services) - a standardized API to both consume and produce RESTful applications. Restlet provides an implementation of this specification.

Following code describes a sample of client with Restlet:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://(...)/contacts");
MyDataBean bean = cr.get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Following code describes a sample of client with JAX-RS:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://(...)")
                         .path("contacts");

MyDataBean bean = target
       .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
       .get(MyDataBean.class);
```

Both tools can leverage content (JSON, XML, YAML, ...) / POJO conversion with for example [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry